# Maven: how do I pass the artifactItems configuration to the dependency copy plugin from the command line?

Tags: maven

I'd like the execute the [Dependency Copy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) from the command line without the need to change the pom.xml file. I need to pass all configuration options from the command line. I can find some references to do it:

```
mvn -DuseRepositoryLayout=true dependency:copy
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set the `<artifactItems><artifactItem>` properties from the command line.

**How would I invoke maven dependency copy plugin passing all necessary parameters in the command line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mix two distinct goals :

- copy-dependencies (referenced in your example) :

> Goal that copies a list of artifacts from the repository to defined
> locations.

- copy (referenced in your link)

> Goal that copies the project dependencies from the repository to a
> defined location.

A user property in a mojo such as `copy-dependencies` provides a way to set a property from the command line with the `-DMyUserProperty` syntax.

From the `copy` plugin documentation you [refer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html), you can read that the `artifact` property has as user property `artifact`.
So the example passing it from the command line is valid :

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=mygroupId:myartifactId:myversion
```

But the same plugin documentation doesn't specify any user property defined for the `artifactItems` property.

Besides, it is clearly stated  :

> Use `artifactItems` within the POM configuration.

So you are stuck to set `artifactItems` from a POM file.

As you don't want to bother with a POM and that you prefer to specify externally the dependencies to copy, [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) that provides a service enough close to which of `copy-dependencies` should better fit to your need as contrary to `copy-dependencies`, it provides a user property to include/exclude artifactIds/groupIds:

> User Property: includeArtifactIds
>
> ...
>
> User Property: includeGroupIds

You could so write something like :

```
 mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DincludeArtifactIds="myArtifactOne,
 myArtifactTwo,..." -DincludeGroupIds="myGroupIdOne, myGroupIdTwo"
```

Comment: Thanks, the link was correct. I've edited the question.

Comment: Great if it could help you !